# Union & Intersect two shapes in Sketch produces odd result. Bug?

Tags: sketch-app

Please focus on the right side of the result shape.

Results of union & intersect are unexpected. Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that looks suspicious. Create a minimal example sketch file and send a bug report.

Comment: Or maybe you can include a link to this file and we can take a look?

Comment: I'd love to see the file as well. Is there an open path somewhere?